# React Hooksでは非同期処理はuseEffect内で行うことと言われていますが、必ずそうしなければならないのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

useEffectを使用する理由としては下記があると思います。

①レンダリング後に処理を行うことができる
②useEffectの第2引数で実行タイミングを制御できる
③アンマウント時のキャンセル処理を設定できる

しかし、逆に言えば上記のいずれも必要ない場合はuseEffectを使用せずに非同期処理を実行してよいということでしょうか？
例えば、Ajaxでサーバーからデータを取得してコンポーネントに表示する処理などは、下記の理由でuseEffectを使用しなくてよい場合がある気がします。

①Ajaxリクエストの発行はレンダリングの終了を待つ必要がない
②コンポーネントのレンダリングがReact.memo等で制御されていればuseEffectなしでも実行タイミングを制御できる
③アンマウント時の処理は特にない

その場合のコードは以下のようになります。

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
axios.get(`https://example.com/api/users/XXX`).then(res => setName(res.data.name));
return (<div>{name}</div>);
```

Comment: useEffectを使用しない場合、どういったコードを想定していますか？是非サンプルコードを掲載してください！

Comment: @hinaloe サンプルコードを追加しました！よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 訂正アンサー

**更新日2022年7月17日**

`useEffect` を使う必要はありません。

もともと `useEffect` が奨励されていた理由の一つに、メモリリーク警告が挙げられますが、この警告は誤解を招くとして React18 で削除されました。

コンポーネントがアンマウントした後に、`setState` などしたときに出るメモリリーク警告は、多くのケースでは実際にはメモリリークには繋がりません。

非同期処理は、シンプルに関数を実行する形で問題ないようです。詳しくは、以下のリンクの Dan Abramovさんの解説をご覧ください。

https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82

### 以下がオリジナルの答え（メモリリーク警告を鵜呑みにした的違いなアンサー）

---

`useEffect` を必ず使うべきというわけではありませんが、`useEffect` を使ったほうがベターです。

個人的には、非同期処理をするときに `useCallback` でやっても動けばいいじゃんとも思いますが、`useEffect` がベスト・プラクティスというのは理解しています。

### サンプルコード

以下のサンプルコードには、大きな問題があります。
それは、レンダリングごとにリクエストが発生してしまう点です。

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
// ↓ コンポーネントがレンダリングされる度に、axios.get が実行される。
// つまり、レンダリングごとにリクエストが発生する！
axios.get(`https://example.com/api/users/XXX`).then(res => setName(res.data.name));
return (<div>{name}</div>);
```

1. 最初の `setName` が実行されたあとに、React の再レンダリング処理が走る
2. レンダリング時に `axios.get()` が実行される

API サーバーに無駄なリクエストが発生してしまい、これは明らかに問題です。

### `useEffect` を使った場合

`useEffect` を使えば、API リクエストが何度も走ることはありません。

```
const Example = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  
  // コンポーネントマウント後に一度だけ実行される
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;

    async function fetchName() {
      // axios ではなく fetch を使いました
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/fetch
      const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/users/XXX');
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`unexpected status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const data = await res.body();
      // アンマウントされた後に setName するとメモリ開放の妨げになるため、デバッガーに警告が出る
      if (!unmounted) {
        setName(data.name);
      }
    }

    fetchName();

    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{name}</div>;
};
```

### ユーザーアクション後に API リクエストするケース (`useCallback`)

次に、APIリクエストのタイミングが、ボタンクリック後のケースも考えてみましょう。
下のケースでは、`useCallback` を使います。

```
// ボタンがクリックされたら名前を読み込む
const Example = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const unmountRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      unmountRef.current = true;
    };
  }, []);
  
  const handleClick = useCallback(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/users/XXX');
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`unexpected status: ${res.status}`);
    }
    const data = await res.body();
    // アンマウントされた後に setName するとメモリ開放の妨げになるため、デバッガーに警告が出る
    if (!unmountRef.current) {
      setName(data.name);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>名前を読み込む</button>
      <div>名前：{name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

このケースでは、アンマウント後に `setName` が実行されるのを防ぐため、`useRef` を使ってマウント状態を保存しています。

### ユーザーアクション後に API リクエストするケース (`useEffect`)

かなり冗長的になってしまいますが、理想的な実装です。

```
// ボタンがクリックされたら名前を読み込む
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "LOAD":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case "SET_NAME":
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        name: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function reset() {
  return {
    isLoading: false,
    name: '',
  };
}

const Example = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, undefined, reset);
  const { isLoading, name } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    let unmounted = false;

    async function fetchName() {
      // axios ではなく fetch を使いました
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/fetch
      const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/users/XXX');
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`unexpected status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const data = await res.body();
      // アンマウントされた後に dispatch するとメモリ開放の妨げになるため、デバッガーに警告が出る
      if (!unmounted) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_NAME", payload: data.name });
      }
    }

    fetchName();

    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [isLoading]);

  const handleClick = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD" });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>名前を読み込む</button>
      <div>名前：{name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

この最後のケースでは、`isLoading` が `true` になったタイミングで API リクエストを実行し、コンポーネントの状態を更新します。

実装に必要なコードの量は増えますが、コードを読んだときのロジックの把握のしやすさといった、メンテナンス性も考慮すると、`useCallback` よりも `useEffect` に軍配が上がるかと思います。

Comment: 複数の回答を投稿することも可能なので、元の内容と異なるのであれば **別の回答** として投稿した方が分かりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 私は、この質問の場合は回答を分離するのには反対です。時間の流れに関係なく議論のできる類の質問であれば話は別ですが、この質問はフレームワークのベストプラクティスに関したものだからです。
ソフトウェア開発の方法論は変化が激しく、時の流れによってベストプラクティスが変わりやすいので、常に手入れをすることが重要だと思います。